# Point Light looks like it's pointed towards a direction

Tags: lighting

I am currently having a strange issue with my blender. My lights for my floor and ceiling aren't looking correct, and sort of look like they are pointing towards one side, which causes one part of mesh to look like it's normally lit, but the other side doesn't look lit at all. This happens with all 4 lights, but I am looking to hopefully use point for this. renderer is Eevee btw, as Cycles takes almost 2 entire days to render this scene :(

[image: Example of the lighting issue]

Comment: Hi Artsmen, since you are new here, i have to tell you that we cannot do mind reading and we have no idea what you did. So i think it is a good idea if you provide your blend file so we can check it out ourselves. thx.

Comment: To add to Chris's words, don't forget to pack all the extra files into this blend file. Otherwise, you can only guess what the problem is. Maybe in the lighting settings, maybe in the fact that you hid objects from the render. There are dozens of options.

Comment: To add to both the previous comments.. :) Please strip your file down to a _minimal_ failing version.

Comment: @Chris Ok, Here you go, [The .blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XGPXO_4eNinmacwBynwL2MTExUAZvwai/view?usp=drive_link) Hopefully this is good.

Comment: i can't really tell if there is anything wrong, in render mode i get https://snipboard.io/sNPAqb.jpg is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: yes, One side (the left) is lit normally, but on the right, the light range or whatever you wanna call it is way shorter, causing that side not to light up as much